# how to create two classes to implement `head body init last`?

Tags: javascript, class, oop, coffeescript

My current code is wrong, but it might be better explaining what I want to do, writtern in CoffeeScript:

```
implement = (the_class) ->
  the_class::__defineGetter__ 'now', -> @[@length - 1]
  the_class::__defineGetter__ 'init', -> @[...(@length - 1)]
  the_class::__defineGetter__ 'head', -> @[0]
  the_class::__defineGetter__ 'body', -> @[1..]

class List extends Array
List::__defineGetter__ 'last', -> @[@length - 1]

class Text extends String


implement List
implement Text

a = new Text 'xxx'
console.log a.now
```

Mainly, I want to use strings and arrays with simple methods like `head init body tail`, in the OOP way as described above. But I don't want to pollute global scope. I was trying to iherent new classes from Array and String, but it failed to work in my code.

Comment: Maybe some explanation would be helpful. And trying to extend native objects such as Array and String generally doesn't work out that well.

Comment: @muistooshort So only solution is create them from scratch?

Comment: Maybe. I'm not really sure what you're trying to accomplish here.

Comment: @muistooshort Added some words just now. I want to use expressions like `"string".tail list.head` to get first or last element. This syntax looks better in programes. If that's can be achieved, I have to use `(head "string") (tail list)`.

Comment: Why not add these directly to `Array.prototype`?

Comment: @Eric I did it, also to `String.prototype`, but polluting global variables is always not the best choice.

Comment: Side note: why `str.now` but `list.tail` or `list.now`? What meaning does `now` have here, and why does a string have no tail?

Comment: @Eric .. English is not my first language, the words here are not accurate, you may replace with better ones. For me there's a use case that I'd like to use strings like arrays, or `.split` them into arrays is another solution. I think that's not the important part of the question.